# Div height auto-adjusting to content

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with these tabs that are not adjusting depending to the height of content. I tried everything I knew, but didn't work. For know I put the height of .acontent 2550px (which is needed to display the content of .acontent-1). But I want when you switch to a different tab the div .acontent to be smaller, relatively to the content of .acontent-2

I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XGvT/

I know there is a lot of code, but the main structure is this one:

```
<section class="tabs">here are the buttons

 <div class="acontent">
  <div class="acontent-1">div that has to auto-adjust
  <div class="acontent-2">div that has to auto-adjust
  <div class="acontent-3">div that has to auto-adjust
```

and the css:

```
.acontent {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2550px;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.acontent>div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    transition: all linear 0.1s;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the height according to content's height, you should use `height:auto;` instead of `height:2550px;`

Comment: You should also remove position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in the css for the tab:

```
height:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding different heights for checked divs:

```
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .acontent{
height:1100px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .acontent{
height:1250px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .acontent{
height:450px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-5:checked ~ .acontent{
height:950px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-6:checked ~ .acontent{
height:700px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-7:checked ~ .acontent{
height:500px !important;
}
.tabs input.tab-selector-8:checked ~ .acontent{
height:800px !important;
}
```